# kube-proxy issues - trying to add a windows worker node to a kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, windows-server-2019

I'm trying to get a [windows (server 2019) based docker container running inside a kubernetes cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/kubernetes/joining-windows-workers?tabs=ManagementIP), using the `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809` image [from here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore)

The node is recognised by the cluster and shown as ready.

When I try to deploy any pod to the cluster it runs without problems, but it's not possible to access the exposed ports associated with the service.

It appears that there's an issue with running `kube-proxy` on the windows worker node. The log for that node show:

`Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "kube-proxy-nwclf": Error response from daemon: network host not found`

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong here?

UPDATE: 
Just noticed that the kube-proxy pod on the windows machine has a cluster based ip address (`10.244.5.2`) rather than one from my local network (`192.168.1.X`). Is this relevant in terms of working out what the problem is?

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                 READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE   IP             NODE              NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system   kube-proxy-9jq8w                     1/1     Running             1          15d   192.168.1.9   k8s-mr        <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-h5gx7                     0/1     ContainerCreating   0          13s   10.244.5.2     wins2019-worker   <none>           <none>
```

Detail from describe pod shown below.

```
user@k8s-mr:~/kube_projects/testdemo-4.1/app$ kubectl -n kube-system describe pod kube-proxy-nwclf
Name:               kube-proxy-nwclf
Namespace:          kube-system
Priority:           2000001000
PriorityClassName:  system-node-critical
Node:               wins2019-worker/192.168.1.10
Start Time:         Wed, 17 Apr 2019 13:35:30 +0100
Labels:             controller-revision-hash=b7775b676
                    k8s-app=kube-proxy
                    pod-template-generation=1
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Pending
IP:                 192.168.1.10
Controlled By:      DaemonSet/kube-proxy
Containers:
  kube-proxy:
    Container ID:
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.14.0
    Image ID:
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy
      --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf
      --hostname-override=$(NODE_NAME)
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      NODE_NAME:   (v1:spec.nodeName)
    Mounts:
      /lib/modules from lib-modules (ro)
      /run/xtables.lock from xtables-lock (rw)
      /var/lib/kube-proxy from kube-proxy (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-proxy-token-f4tqx (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-proxy:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      kube-proxy
    Optional:  false
  xtables-lock:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /run/xtables.lock
    HostPathType:  FileOrCreate
  lib-modules:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /lib/modules
    HostPathType:
  kube-proxy-token-f4tqx:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  kube-proxy-token-f4tqx
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:
                 CriticalAddonsOnly
                 node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/network-unavailable:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute
                 node.kubernetes.io/pid-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute
                 node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                From                      Message

------

  Normal   Scheduled               70s                default-scheduler         Successfully assigned kube-system/kube-proxy-nwclf to wins2019-worker
  Normal   SandboxChanged          2s (x12 over 61s)  kubelet, wins2019-worker  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  0s (x13 over 62s)  kubelet, wins2019-worker  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "kube-proxy-nwclf": Error response from daemon: network host not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it now, I had misunderstood that `kube-proxy` should not run at all on the windows node.

I had to amend the kubernetes master and apply a `NodeSelector` to ensure that the appropriate pods are setup for each node based on its OS.

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/SDN/master/Kubernetes/flannel/l2bridge/manifests/node-selector-patch.yml
kubectl patch ds/kube-proxy --patch "$(cat node-selector-patch.yml)" -n=kube-system
```